# Enable wso2 self registration for service provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 5.1.1 .I can see the create account when i access dashboard.

But it is not seen in the authentication endpoint of the service provider.

Is it possible to enable/disable this feature based on service provider??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently In IS 5.1.0, it only support self sign up via IS dashboard. So you can't enable/disable this based on service provider. 
If you need to add self sign up for other service providers either you will have to customize authentication endpoint webapp or provide a different page for register an user using `UserRegistrationAdminService`. Refer [this page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Customizing+Login+Pages+for+Service+Providers) for more information on customizing the login page.

Comment: UserRegistrationAdminServiceClient has an addUser method whose input parameters are username,password and userFields.How can i add user with tenant domain as suggested in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/User+Information+Recovery+Service#UserInformationRecoveryService-registerUser

Comment: can you try username@tenant.com as username?